# image DataTemplate inside a contentcontrol WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, image, datatemplate, contentcontrol

i have a DataTemplate

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="image">
  <Image x:Name="TheImage" />
     <DataTemplate.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=OverallResult}">
                <DataTrigger.Value>
                    <local:resultType>Success</local:resultType>
                </DataTrigger.Value>
                <Setter TargetName="TheImage" Property="Source" Value="bin/Debug/Input/successx.jpg" />
            </DataTrigger>
 </DataTemplate>
```

with some trigger setters That Works fine in a GridView

```
  <ListView Margin="292,54,0,50" Name="listViewCaseSequence" MinHeight="215" Width="203" Button.Click="OnClick" ItemsSource="{Binding TestCaseSequenceList}" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Result" CellTemplate="{StaticResource image}" Width="40"/>
      ...
```

now i would like to use it in some kind of StackPanel. I already found out that i could use a ContentControle

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
   <!-- doenst work --> <ContentControl ContentTemplate="{StaticResource image}" Content="{Binding OverallResult}" />
   <!-- works --> <TextBlock Text="{Binding OverallResult}" />
</StackPanel>
```

The TextBlock works fine. But im missing something at the ContentControle thats doesnt let it render the image?

A pointer to the right reading source would be fine too :) 
Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

```
 ...
 <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding}">
 ...
 <ContentControl ContentTemplate="{StaticResource image}" Content="{Binding OverallResult}"/>
 ...
```

Output Says:
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'OverallResult' property not found on 'object' ''resultType' (HashCode=0)'. BindingExpression:Path=OverallResult; DataItem='resultType' (HashCode=0); target element is 'ContentPresenter' (Name=''); target property is 'NoTarget' (type 'Object')

But why does he find the  >OverallResult< on the Textblock thats works ?

**EDIT2:** Still not working

```
 ...
 <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding}">
 ...
 <ContentControl ContentTemplate="{StaticResource image}"/>
 ...
```

**Edit3:** Working:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=OverallResult}">
<ContentControl ContentTemplate="{StaticResource image}" Content="{Binding}"/>
```

Comment: looks like the `Triggers` stop working due to the fact that the DataContext is changed when you use the DataTemplate in the StackPanel. More code about the `DataTemplate` with its Triggers would be helpful here. You can also try looking in the ***Output*** window to see if there is any error notified there.

Comment: i updated the DataTriggers, The output Window doenst show anything when i fill the stackpanel via Button

Comment: you use `TargetName` in DataTemplate, it's strange to know that it works when used in the ListView because I think it should not even work at all. I suppose the `TheImage` is placed outside the DataTemplate, so `TargetName` should not work in this case (unless you've still not shown all the code inside the DataTemplate maybe including the `TheImage`)

Comment: Updated Again, sorry. `<Image x:Name="TheImage" />` is indeed in the code.

Comment: I think I've found the problem, please check out my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DataContext` in the `DataTemplate` here is in fact the `Content` you set for the `ContentControl`. Because it's already set to `{Binding OverallResult}`, so the Binding inside DataTemplate should be just `{Binding}` like this:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="image">
   <Image x:Name="TheImage" />
   <DataTemplate.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding}">
            <DataTrigger.Value>
                <local:resultType>Success</local:resultType>
            </DataTrigger.Value>
            <Setter TargetName="TheImage" Property="Source" 
                    Value="bin/Debug/Input/successx.jpg" />
        </DataTrigger>
   </DataTemplate.Triggers>
 </DataTemplate>
```

The above template should of course be used only for the StackPanel. For the ListView, just use the old DataTemplate.

However I think the `Content` you set for the `ContentControl` in this case can be just `{Binding}`, then the DataContext in both cases (for ListView and ContentControl) should be the same and we can use just one DataTemplate:

```
<ContentControl ContentTemplate="{StaticResource image}" Content="{Binding}"/>
```

Comment: It doesn't work. And now both, the ItemView and the Stackpanel don't work. Is there something linke Content for the ` <GridViewColumn` so that i can test it there?

Comment: @DormaPadre the DataTemplate I modified of course does not work for the ListView, but it should work for the StackPanel. You simply cannot use the same DataTemplate for both because the DataContexts are different and the same Bindings used inside DataTemplate won't work expectedly. Please try looking in the ***Output*** window to see if there is any error notified there.

Comment: @DormaPadre from the error, it's obvious that the implicit DataContext of the StackPanel is just some object of type `resultType`. I'm sure that object does not have any property `OverallResult`, but it's strange that the `TextBlock` binding works (as you said). You should try double checking it, try commenting out  and just keep the `TextBlock`. It would be better if you use ***Snoop*** to monitor the visual tree.